# Facebook C# sdk random exception when posting photo

Tags: windows-services, facebook-c#-sdk, unhandled-exception

I am using Facebook C#sdk to upload photos to user profiles using a Windows Service as a background job. And I am logging exceptions in almost every place that I can think of and for the most part it works fine. But occasionally, and sometimes it is quite frequent, I get the following exception, which does not get caught by my handler, and gets logged by the Windows Event logger, and terminates my service:

```
Application: PhotoService.exe    
Framework Version: v4.0.30319    
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Exception    
Stack:
at System.Net.Security._SslStream.WriteCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr)
at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

From the looks of it, this is happening at FacebookClient.PostTaskAsync() method call, but I have no idea how to troubleshoot with the limited stacktrace information. Below is my photo posting method block:

```
public void PostPhotoToTimeline(string filename, byte[] photo, EventHandler<FacebookApiEventArgs> callbackCompleted)
{
    var _filename = filename;
    var mediaObject = new FacebookMediaObject
    {
        ContentType = "image/jpeg",
        FileName = _filename
    }.SetValue(photo);

    _fb.PostCompleted += callbackCompleted;
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters["file"] = mediaObject;

    _fb.PostTaskAsync("/me/photos", parameters);
}
```

My biggest problem at the moment is, when this exception occurs, it terminates the service and I don't have service monitoring set up yet, so no way for me to find out the service has stopped. If I understand it correctly, this exception occurs in a separate thread and is not handled, thus it brings down the whole service. Is this correct? Any idea why this might be happening and where, or anyone faced this exception before? I have read about 'legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy' to catch these unexpected exceptions. Will this prevent my service from terminating and is it good idea to use it? Sorry if I am asking too many questions in one go but these are all related and google hasn't been my friend on this so far. 
Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 months gone and not a single answer, so I will post what I did to prevent this issue which might be useful to others. Still don't know the main cause for the crash but it is occasional, so using the flag "legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy" has worked so far, with no unexpected terminations. The flag needs to be enabled in the config file:

```
<runtime>
<legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1"/>
</runtime>
```

Better explanation here: [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965.aspx)